# Matrix derivative with respect to an orthogonal matrix

Tags: partial-derivative

Consider the following function:

$$\ f(U)= UU^TXUU^TY $$

where $\ U \in \Re^{n*m} $ ,$\ U^TU = I_m$ and X and Y are Symmetric positive definite matrices with dimension $\ n$.

What is the derivative of $\ f(U)$ with respect to $\ U$ ?

Thank you so much

Comment: @Fimpellizieri what I guess is: $\ 4YUU^TXU $

Comment: How could the derivative of a function from $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ into $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a $n\times m$ matrix? (Apart from the trivial case $n=1$)